# How to load doctrine fixtures if we have multiple databases and connections

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4, fixtures

I used this documentation : https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

So now I can create new databases named legacy and Project like this

**doctrince.yaml:**

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
    default_connection: legacy
    connections:
      legacy:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        host: "%env(database_host)%"
        port: "%env(database_port)%"
        dbname: "%env(database_name)%"
        user: "%env(database_user)%"
        password: "%env(database_password)%"
        charset: UTF8
      project:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        host: "%env(database_host_project)%"
        port: "%env(database_port_project)%"
        dbname: "%env(database_name_project)%"
        user: "%env(database_user_project)%"
        password: "%env(database_password_project)%"
        charset: UTF8
  orm:
    default_entity_manager: legacy
    entity_managers:
      legacy:
        connection: legacy
        mappings:
          Legacy:
            is_bundle: false
            type: annotation
            dir: "%kernel.project_dir%/..."
            prefix: '...'
            alias: Legacy
      project:
        connection: project
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
          Project:
            is_bundle: false
            type: annotation
            dir: "%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity"
            prefix: 'App\Entity'
            alias: Project
```

Now I have several Fixture classes all of them depend on each other and also some will create fixture for legacy and some will create for project.

Now my question is when I do:

`php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --em=legacy`

It runs the appfixtures of the project but not the of the bundle.
and then i get this error:

> The class .. was not found in the chain configured namespaces ....

My question is now how can I load fixtures on multiple databases with multiple connections.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should read this doc : https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

I think it may solve your problem as this is exactly what you trying to do.

If you have to create a fixture for legacy just use :

```
$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('legacy');`
```

else if it is for project use

```
$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('project');`
```

Also, if you change `doctrine.dbal.default_connection`, entityManager will run against the defined connection.

So you can try to create [group of fixtures](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-fixturesbundle-group-your-fixtures).

And then run fixtures for `project` :

1. Edit config for test environment

```
#config/packages/test/doctrine.yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: 'project'
```

2. Then run fixture for 'project' group

```
> php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --group=project
```

Then do the same thing for 'legacy'

Comment: But for the fixtures we are using `ObjectManager` like so ```public function load(ObjectManager $manager): void
    {...```

Comment: You are right, I have edited my answer so I hope you it'll help you.

Comment: Isn't ```$this``` a ```Fixture```? From what I can see in Symfony 5, ```Fixture``` has no ```getDoctrine()```.   Is see the OP is for Symfony 4, has this changed then?